# How to allow only digits to be entered in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I am trying to write a program that receives a 10 digit phone number from the user.
It must only be 10 characters long.
It can only consist of digits. Entering a alphabet character or special character will give an error message. 
I have tried using the `isdigits()` function but that doesn't seem to work. 
Here is my code so far.

Is there any other way to do this without using `isdigits()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void clearKeyboard(void);

int main (void)
{
    char phoneNum[11];
    int needInput = 1;
    int i;
    int flagBad = 0;
    while (needInput == 1) {
        scanf_s("%10s", phoneNum);
        clearKeyboard();
        // (String Length Function: validate entry of 10 characters)
        if (strlen(phoneNum) == 10) {
            needInput = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (isdigits(phoneNum[i] == 0)) {
                    flagBad = 1;
                }
            }
            if (flagBad == 1) {
                needInput = 1;
                printf("Enter a 10-digit phone number: ");
            }
        }
        else needInput == 0;    
    }
    printf("Successful");
    return 0;
}

void clearKeyboard(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n'); // empty execution code block on purpose
}
```

Comment: First the function is isdigit() and second you need to write only the character you want to check in the braces, isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0..

Comment: `if (isdigits(phoneNum[i] == 0)) {` is comparing `phoneNum[i]` to zero, then checking whether the result of the comparison, which will be 1 or 0, is a digit character... which it never will be.  You probably want `if (isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0) {` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s("%10s", phoneNum);` fails as it is missing an argument. Review your `scanf_s()` documentation.

---

I do not recommend `scanf_s()`.  Instead avoid mixing user I/O with input validation.  Get the input, then validate it.

```
   char buf[80]; // Be generous.
   if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
     buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential \n
     // OK we have the input, now validate.

     char phoneNum[11];
     int n = 0;
     // Use sscanf, isdigit, or ...
     if (sscanf(buf, "%10[0-9]", phoneNum, &n) == 1 && n == 10 && buf[n]==0) {
       puts("Success");
     } else {
       printf("Bad input <%s>\n", buf);
     }
```

---

`"%10[0-9]%n", phoneNum, &n` --> Scan 1 to 10 digits into `phoneNum[]` and append a `'\0'`.  Save scanning offset into `n`

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you need is [`isdigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm), not `isdigits()`.

Comment: That was a typo, still doesnt work if I fix it. I'm wondering now if there is a way to validate that an array only has numbers without using that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scanf("%10s", phoneNum);` and also include `#include <stdlib.h>` which contains `isdigit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As AbdelAziz stated, you should use is [isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm), not `isdigits()`.
Also, your if statement is wrong:

```
if (isdigits(phoneNum[i] == 0))
```

should be:

```
if (isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0)
```